# Paypal URL parameters

Tags: url, paypal

I'm looking for a list of Paypal URL parameters to make a link specific to a certain request(i.e. person to person, not merchant transactions).  I have looked on the Paypal site and didn't find what I was looking for... :( Most of the stuff on Google was for "Merchant" type transactions.

Ultimately, I want to create a url to send to people to be able to click on and it automatically sets the values for the amount, currency, payment type(Friends and Family), etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [PayPal Standard Variable Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/) to see all of the parameters you can use.

Comment: The link is broken =/